# Breakpoints in XCTest method hit, but breakpoints in code being tested not hit

Tags: swift, breakpoints, xctest, lldb, xctestcase

Currently unable to debug my code as breakpoints don't seem to be working properly.

I have a test method that is part of an `XCTestCase` that fails. I place a breakpoint into this to debug it and find out that the method on the class I am calling to test is failing. I want to know why. If I try and step into this call, the code stops breaking and the test just fails. If I have a breakpoint in this code, it's never hit.

How can I debug my code? Am I missing something?

Comment: Check if your target code has been compiled with debug symbols/ test build is Debug. Something I have been caught by before by switching my debug optimisation to release to check something.

Comment: Good suggestion but alas, not that easy in my case by the looks of it.

Comment: By default lldb won't `step into` code with no debug information, so it may be that your code has no debug information.  Make sure that the "Generate Debug Symbols" setting is checked in the Build Settings for your project/this configuration.

Comment: Also make sure that "Strip debug symbols during copy" is not on for this configuration.

Comment: If you are on macOS, you can tell for sure whether your library has debug information.  Run `nm -ap <YourLibrary> | grep OSO`.  Run that on the actual binary, not the outer bundle directory.  This should output a list of all the .o files that were built into that library.  If it doesn't then either the .o files weren't built with debug info or the library was stripped...